# Cannot get method added to GORM object using AST transformation

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, abstract-syntax-tree

Here is my GORM object

```
@UpdatedProperties
class Cart {
    Date lastUpdated
    Date dateCreated

    String name 
}
```

Here is annotation definition:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@GroovyASTTransformationClass(["UpdatedPropertiesASTTransformation"])

public @interface UpdatedProperties {
}
```

Here is the AST definition

```
@GroovyASTTransformation(phase = CompilePhase.CLASS_GENERATION)
class UpdatedPropertiesASTTransformation implements ASTTransformation{
    //...

    public void visit(ASTNode[] astNodes, SourceUnit sourceUnit) {
        astNodes.findAll { node -> node instanceof ClassNode}.each {
        classNode ->
            def testMethodBody = new AstBuilder().buildFromString (
                    """
                    println(">>*************myMethod)";
                    """
            )

            def myMethod = new MethodNode('myMethod', ACC_PUBLIC, ClassHelper.VOID_TYPE, [] as Parameter[], [] as ClassNode[], testMethodBody[0])
            classNode.addMethod(myMethod)   
        }
    }
...
}
```

WhenI try to invoke the method I get:

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Cart.myMethod() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Any tips appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: and make sure the transformer is called!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class Generation is too late a compile phase in which to add a method to a class, so you'll need to change your compile phase to either Semantic Analysis or Canonicalization. (This was probably much later than you wanted for adding a method, anyway. [Groovy Compile Phase Guide](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Compiler+Phase+Guide))

There are also a couple of problems in your AST String. There's a syntax error in your println, `println(">>*************myMethod)";` should read `println(">>*************myMethod");`, and you'll need to add an explicit `return;` statement, since you're returning `void` (otherwise Groovy will add a `return null;` at the end of your method and this will clash with your `void` return type).